# How to add custom block link to email template and link hit from email to specific page?

Tags: magento2, frontend, email-templates

How to add custom block link to email template and link hit from email to specific page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're having two ways:

1) Block and template: (not recommended, should try with the second way. I think it's easier)

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Vendor_Module::email/custom.phtml'}}
```

In your `email/custom.phtml template`, we can add your links here.

2) Insert Variable...

[image]

For example: `{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}yourpage`